# If text value occurs more than 3 times in range, true / false

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

In the example below, I want to count all of the duplicates in the range `A2:I2` and if there are more than three of the same occurrence, `true` else `false` I tried `>3`assuming it would show true if the count of unique values were greater than three.

In the image below the formula would return true since there are more than three occurrences of any text value in the range `A2:I2`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A2:I2,A2:I2))>3
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put the `>3` inside the SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(A2:I2,A2:I2)>3))>0
```

Now it will return True if any one value is there more than 3 times.